# App Transport Security error despite changing info.plist to NSAppTransport Security to NO Xcode 7.2 iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, security, http

I am using Xcode 7.2 and I am facing a problem in iOS 9.2.
As suggested for previous versions in order to solve.

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

problem I inserted the following lines on my info.plist file:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.mydomain.gr</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and it worked great since the 9.2 iOS version where the same message appear again.

I tried to turn `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to YES and it worked but I am sure that this is not the right way to solve it because Apple may reject my application that way.
I am thinking of changing my URL from http to https. Could that be the solution? Has anyone the same problem?

Comment: I also add the BOOL key `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` set to YES.

Comment: Is the www required for that domain?

Comment: As far as I can see no!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [GlennRay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597877/glennray) I finally found the solution.

First of all I inserted a certificate in my domain in order to have secured connection and I replaced all of my urls to https. So there was no need anymore to use any of the mentioned variables in the plist file so I deleted them. 

And one crucial think was that I should delete the www from my domain since it was not required!

Comment: Hmmm, should I put the www thought in as a answer?

Comment: It is the www along with the insertion of the certificate for having a secured connection! I do not know!